# cant open my partions after reboot

Tags: dual-boot

when i try to open any partion i find this error

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/mano/upnto: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda5" "/media/mano/upnto"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

but  when i try to mount it i get this error

```
mount: special device /dev/sda5 does not exist
```

Comment: `sda5` != `sdb5`

Answer (score 2):

First, like the error message says, `Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)` - fix this problem in Windows.

Second, if your disk is `/dev/sda5`, why did you try to mount `/dev/sdb5`? That won't work.